# Async WCF Service with multiple async calls inside

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a web service in WCF that consume some external web services, so what I want to do is make this service asynchronous in order to release the thread, wait for the completion of all the external services, and then return the result to the client.

## With Framework 4.0

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public IAsyncResult BeginDoWork(int count, AsyncCallback callback, object serviceState)
    {    
        var proxyOne = new Gateway.BackendOperation.BackendOperationOneSoapClient();
        var proxyTwo = new Gateway.BackendOperationTwo.OperationTwoSoapClient();

        var taskOne = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(proxyOne.BeginGetNumber, proxyOne.EndGetNumber, 10, serviceState);
        var taskTwo = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(proxyTwo.BeginGetNumber, proxyTwo.EndGetNumber, 10, serviceState);
        
        var tasks = new Queue<Task<int>>();
        tasks.Enqueue(taskOne);
        tasks.Enqueue(taskTwo);

        return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), innerTasks =>
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>(serviceState);
            int sum = 0;

            foreach (var innerTask in innerTasks)
            {
                if (innerTask.IsFaulted)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(innerTask.Exception);
                    callback(tcs.Task);
                    return;
                }

                if (innerTask.IsCompleted)
                {
                    sum = innerTask.Result;
                }
            }

            tcs.SetResult(sum);

            callback(tcs.Task);
        });
    }

    public int EndDoWork(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            return ((Task<int>)result).Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }

    }
}
```

My questions here are:

1. This code is using three threads: one that is instanced in the
   BeginDoWork, another one that is instanced when the code enter
   inside the anonymous method ContinueWhenAll, and the last one when
   the callback is executed, in this case EndDoWork. Is that correct or
   I’m doing something wrong on the calls? Should I use any
   synchronization context? Note:  The synchronization context is null
   on the main thread.
2. What happen if I “share” information between
   threads, for instance, the callback function? Will that cause a
   performance issue or the anonymous method is like a closure where I
   can share data?

## With Framework 4.5 and Async and Await

Now with Framework 4.5, the code seems too much simple than before:

```
    public async Task<int> DoWorkAsync(int count)
    {
        var proxyOne = new Backend.ServiceOne.ServiceOneClient();
        var proxyTwo = new Backend.ServiceTwo.ServiceTwoClient();

        var doWorkOne = proxyOne.DoWorkAsync(count);
        var doWorkTwo = proxyTwo.DoWorkAsync(count);

        var result = await Task.WhenAll(doWorkOne, doWorkTwo);

        return doWorkOne.Result + doWorkTwo.Result;
    }
```

But in this case when I debug the application, I always see that the code is executed on the same thread. So my questions here are:

3.. When I’m waiting for the “awaitable” code, is that thread released and goes back to the thread pool to execute more requests?

3.1. If So, I suppose that when I get a result from the await Task, the execution completes on the same thread that the call before. Is that possible? What happen if that thread is processing another request?

3.2 If Not, how can I release the thread to send it back to the thread pool with Asycn and Await pattern?

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, with the async targeting pack, you can use async/await with 4.0 projects.

Comment: Can the 4.0 return Task<int> (even if it doesn't use async/await)?  That'd simplify that code a bit, I'd think. Task<T> implements IAsyncResult IIRC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. This code is using three threads: one that is instanced in the BeginDoWork, another one that is instanced when the code enter inside the anonymous method ContinueWhenAll, and the last one when the callback is executed, in this case EndDoWork. Is that correct or I’m doing something wrong on the calls? Should I use any synchronization context?

It's better to think in terms of "tasks" rather than "threads". You do have three tasks here, each of which will run on the thread pool, one at a time.

> 2. What happen if I “share” information between threads, for instance, the callback function? Will that cause a performance issue or the anonymous method is like a closure where I can share data?

You don't have to worry about synchronization because each of these tasks can't run concurrently. `BeginDoWork` registers the continuation just before returning, so it's already practically done when the continuation can run. `EndDoWork` will probably not be called until the continuation is complete; but even if it is, it will block until the continuation is complete.

(Technically, the continuation *can* start running before `BeginDoWork` completes, but `BeginDoWork` just returns at that point, so it doesn't matter).

> 3. When I’m waiting for the “awaitable” code, is that thread released and goes back to the thread pool to execute more requests?

Yes.

> 3.1. If So, I suppose that when I get a result from the await Task, the execution completes on the same thread that the call before. Is that possible? What happen if that thread is processing another request?

No. Your host (in this case, ASP.NET) may continue the `async` methods on any thread it happens to have available.

This is perfectly safe because only one thread is executing *at a time*.

P.S. I recommend

```
var result = await Task.WhenAll(doWorkOne, doWorkTwo);
return result[0] + result[1];
```

instead of

```
var result = await Task.WhenAll(doWorkOne, doWorkTwo);
return doWorkOne.Result + doWorkTwo.Result;
```

because `Task.Result` should be avoided in `async` programming.

Comment: For the last bit of code, what's the pros/cons of just doing var result1 = await doWorkOne; var result2 = await doWorkTwo; and then adding them?  Avoids the 'wrapper' task, although that's probably negligible.

Comment: WRT the 'may continue on any thread', I thought that wasn't true due to asp.net sync context and not using ConfigureAwait(false);?

Comment: @James: the `await doWorkOne(); await doWorkTwo()" approach starts `One` and then doesn't start `Two` until after `One` completes. The `WhenAll(doWorkOne(), doWorkTwo())` approach starts them both and then continues when they're both complete. So it's a simple form of parallelism.

Comment: The ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` represents a *request* context. It's perfectly valid for the `async` method to resume on a different thread, as long as it has the correct request context. The request context does allow only one thread in at a time, but it's not always the same thread. Just saw a [great video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET) on `async` ASP.NET - they covered practically everything in about an hour!

Comment: I meant with doWorkOne and doWorkTwo as already-started tasks, as in your code snippets.

Comment: I was wondering why *you* would ask that! :) Yes, the individual `await`s would avoid the additional task, but also [add more code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/15/async-ctp-refresh-design-changes.aspx) to the `async` method. I don't know which one would be (faster | less memory intensive) in practice - most of my experience is still on VS2010+AsyncCTP, which is not optimized at all (making perf testing meaningless). Moving to VS2012 in ~2 weeks...

Comment: What is the problem with `Task.Result` in `async` programming?

Comment: @PeetBrits: It easily causes a [deadlock scenario that I explain on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Also, `Result` means you're *not* doing asynchronous programming; you lose all the benefits of `async` in the first place.

Comment: @Stephen : In the above example, `doWorkX.Result` should not be a problem as all the tasks are already completed (thanks to the previous `await Task.WhenAll(myTask, myOtherTask, ...)`). In that case, there's no thread transition because there's no wait (the result is already available). So the `Results` seems perfectly valid to me in asynchronous programming if it's not used to wait for the task completion. Do you agree ? Did I missed something ?

Comment: @JYL: In this specific example, `Result` cannot cause a deadlock. However, I still don't recommend it. For one thing, it would only work because there's an earlier `await Task.WhenAll` in that method for that task. So the code is much more brittle, with implicit dependencies on earlier logic. Using the result of `WhenAll` (or in the more general case, `await` instead of `Result`) is at least as easy as using `Result`, and is much more maintainable. Also, `Result` wraps any exceptions within `AggregateException`, which complicates error handling. Also see [my blog](http://tinyurl.com/j5tvzq5).